# Exported consts are undefined (Angular, TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript, cesiumjs

I have one file which declares some constants, like this:

```
// color-constants.ts: no imports in this file
export const aoiToImageMaterial = new Cesium.ColorMaterialProperty(
    new Cesium.Color(0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.1)
);

export const aoiToImageOutline = new Cesium.Color(0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1);
```

However, when I import these into my Angular component file, they return `undefined`:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Aoi } from '../../../models/aoi.model';
import * as colorConstants from '../../color-constants';

@Component({
  selector: 'cs-aoi',
  templateUrl: './aoi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./aoi.component.scss']
})
export class AoiComponent {
  @Input('aoi') aoi: Aoi;

  materialProperty;
  outlineColor;

  constructor() {
    this.materialProperty = colorConstants.aoiToImageMaterial; // undefined
    this.outlineColor = colorConstants.aoiToImageOutline; // undefined
  }

}
```

If I declare these constants in the component file, it works as expected, so the problem is the import/export. The `color-constants.ts` file does not import anything, so I doubt it's a circular dependency problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have something like `declare const Cesium: any;` in that file?

Comment: In which file? Cesium is defined in a type file and is available globally.

Comment: damn... 5 years later and no help. I'm getting exactly the same issue.